# zf2 insert using $db->insert($table, $data); style

Tags: php, database, insert, zend-framework2

Hello is there any way to insert data in a db table using the zf1 style on zf2?

```
$db->insert('tablename', $data);
```

where `$data` is an associative array contains (**columns**, **values**)

thanks

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make an insert in zf2:

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $insert = $sql->insert('table');
    $newData = array(
    'col1'=> 'val1',
    'col2'=> 'val2',
    'col3'=> 'val3'
    );
    $insert->values($newData);
    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
    $results = $this->dbAdapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Comment: getSqlStringForSqlObject() is deprecated in 2.4

Comment: buildSqlString() should handle the same in this case.

Comment: How to get the insert ID?

Answer (score 4):

My proposition using TableGateway:

```
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $otherTable = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('table_name', $adapter);
    $otherTable->insert($data));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\EventManager\EventsCapableInterface' not found .. seems this require another module?

Comment: I have this way only, but I am surprised it is making two entries why so ?
    $otherTable = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('demo',          \Config\Config::getAdapter());
$otherTable->insert(['name' => 500]);