# How can I insert data to mysql with zf2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I want to insert a data from index Controller. But how will I set up database object and 
call a insert function in indexAction?

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [zf2 insert using $db->insert($table, $data); style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260525/zf2-insert-using-db-inserttable-data-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create database connection, take a look here -  [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html)

and for inserting expressions into database - check here  [link](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Database-Inserting-Expressions-to-a-table-P495.html)

Youd $db must be defined globally if you are using only zend database adapter.